# Через каждые два символа вставлять /

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как написать выражение.
Пример 11/11/11.
Попробовал так, получается 11 /11, а при удаление появляются новые /.

```
return value.replace(/\s+/g, '/').replace(/(\d{2})/g, '$1 ').trim();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то вы очень странно регулярку пишете. Вот вставляет / через 2 символа.

```js
document.getElementById("mytext").value="123456"
function myreplace() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
  var x=elem.replace(/../g,"$&/").replace(/\/$/g,"");
  document.getElementById("output").value=x;
}
```

```html
<input id="mytext" type="text">
<button onclick="myreplace();">test</button>
<input id="output" type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно поняла вопрос, будет просто:
   value.replace(/(\d{2})/g, '$1/').trim();

Comment: Еще нужно в конце / удалить.